# How to extract the node js code base from bundled exe file?

Tags: javascript, node.js, exe

I'm working on a task where I've been given an exe file of Node.JS application. I don't have the complete  code and I even don't know which npm module was used to create exe file.

Now my task is to extract the code from exe file and make changes to the code.

Is it possible to extract the code from exe file without having the actual code base and are there any modules available for that.

Appreciate the response in advance.

Comment: I can’t wait to see the answers to this but all I’m going to say is, think about the security issues that would be exposed if that were possible, not to mention the IP that would be stolen if not open source. If it’s possible, I’ll be blown away.

Comment: Yes, I totally agree with you about security issues. But the thing here is, even the owner has lost the whole code base and asking the developer to find the workaround